# What are some obvious and non-obvious arguments for the Handy Pan?

Tags: non-obviousness

This product appeared in an episode of Shark Tank.

Seems pretty obvious to me. Strainers exist. Pans exists. Bowls with strainers exist.

[image]

Comment: Do you assume there is a patent issued? If so, people can look it up. Otherwise one would need to understand the purpose and operation of the device to make a reasonable response. Cylinders of metal existed, crooked metal shafts existed, flammable liquids existed, sparks could be made - why was the internal combustion engine a big deal. Oh, the particular interrelationship makes a big difference.

Comment: A quick search shows 2 design patents.  The utility applications have yet to be granted.

Comment: At least one of the utility applications has been abandoned.